# how to move iframe on mouse over using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I am attempting to move an iframe on `mouseover` in jQuery. I have had some success with this by capturing the mouse position within the iframe, but the flicker off the movement is extreme.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wUdk4/1/) is a jsfiddle example

As far as I can see, the reason for the flicker is that every time the iframe moves the x position inside the iframe jumps in the opposite direction, but I can not figure a way of fixing it.

Comment: What are you expecting / trying to achieve with your code? Should it be stuck to mouse or?

Comment: what is the goal...move the contents of iframe, or move the iframe itself?

Comment: Moving the iframe so it sticks to the mouse with a smooth action is the current goal. I am not able to show the complete concept in jsfiddle as it is for mobile touch rather then mouse, but the idea will be that the frame can be moved by touching a handle element within it but without preventing interaction with the rest of the frame.

Comment: Got it going smooth to the right DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/54RhN/  I'm guessing when mouse leaves the iframe on left you want it to come back? Should be easy enough now...getting late here but I bet what I did will help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietf,

Thanks for your efforts, it did indeed lead me in the right direction and I have given a vote to your comment.

The only problem with your example is that as the iframe x position changed the e.pageX changes with it. This means it always equals 0 (or close to).

To get past this I had to add a variable that captures the mouse position within the iframe before any movement has taken place and then remove this number from the x variable when moving the frame.

For anyone out  there looking for something similar, [here is an update version of charlietf's script with the changes written in](http://jsfiddle.net/7KR4t/). I have also changed from  mouseover mouseout events to mousedown mouseup in order to make it easier to play with.

Now I can drag an iframe around from any non active part of my iframe;